# Get tile images directly from sqlite database

Tags: tiles, sqlite

I'm trying to get map tile images to display in my application. I created a sqlite database and used WMS Lite server to request map tiles using GetMap syntax.

```
wmslite?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION&REQUEST=GetMap&BBOX=xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax&CRS=EPSG:3857&STYLES=&FORMAT=image/png&WIDTH=512&HEIGHT=512&LAYERS=test
```

But WMS Lite is not reliable because it crashes so often. So now I'm trying to get the tiles directly from the sqlite database. Is there anyway that I can download the tiles similar to the GetMap syntax.

Comment: What is your client? Is your server local or remote?

Comment: I use sqlite so it's local and no server. I want to get the data directly from sqlite file (for example let's call it earth.sqlite).

Comment: And what is your client? And what format is within your sqlite (spatialite, mbtiles, geopackage, your own format)?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm quite new to this. So I don't get what you're asking. I'm writing an app using C# that has a map, and the application will download the map as an image to display in it. I used this tutorial to create the database. https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/librasterlite2/wiki?name=planetEarth if that's what you're asking. Sorry, English isn't my first language.

Comment: No problem :) You say "the application will download the map", does this mean the user would have the app without the data and that the map/database would be "elsewhere" (eg. on a server)?

Comment: It will have the online map via Google map, that one works fine. But I also want to create a local map as well, which means that the sqlite file will be in the same place with the app, not on a server.